# MS SQL script to return a count of records created per day, when time is included in the DATE field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a script (using MS SQL Server 2008 R2) that will give me a count of total rows added to a table, per day, during the last week.  I have used the following script to do this:

```
select date_published, count(customer_id)
from CustomerTable
WHERE date_published >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)
GROUP BY date_published
```

This script works, but the problem I have is that the date_published column in my table needs to contain the time as well, so I need to figure out how to have the script only look at the date portion of the date_published column when it is calculating the totals.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

```
select Convert(date,date_published), count(customer_id) 
from CustomerTable 
WHERE datediff(d,getdate(),date_published )>-7
GROUP BY Convert(date,date_published)
```

Comment: Why did you change the where clause? It is better to do the calculation on a constant than on a column because then the query might be able to use an index to filter the rows needed. As it is in your query a table scan i required.

Comment: Because I prefer clarity over premature optimisation

Comment: How do you know that the optimization already done by the OP is premature?

Comment: It was you who claimed it was a premature optimization. I have claimed nothing except that your query is a bad query and as such I think it should not be in here misleading readers to believe that this is a good way to write a where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try and amend your `GROUP BY date_published` to:

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date_published))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(date_published as date) as date_published,
       count(customer_id) as count_customer_id
from CustomerTable
where date_published >= dateadd(day, -7, cast(getdate() as date))
group by cast(date_published as date)
```